# Canjs Not Routing

Tags: javascript, url-routing, canjs, canjs-routing

so this bug is killing me as I have no clue what's going on, I updated my canjs version to the latest which is currently 2.0.4 with jquery, and the router stopped working. Is not routing anything, I try with window.location.hash and can.route.attr and is not routing. The thing that bugs me is that with the old version I had was working perfectly. Here is the code

```
var Router = can.Control({
    'init': function() {
    },
    'route' : function(){
        window.location.hash = '#!dashboard';
    },
    'dashboard route': function() {
        console.log('dashboard')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    can.route.ready(false);
    new Router($('body'));
    can.route.ready(true);
});
```

Comment: To add to @air_hadoken's correct answer, this should be the only major breaking change when upgrading form 1.1.x to 2.0.x: http://canjs.com/guides/migrating.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, the latest CanJS is 2.0.5, released yesterday.

`can.route.ready()` doesn't work like it used to.  `can.route.ready(true)` in fact does nothing, in order to prevent multiple route setups in legacy code.  This explains somewhat why your code isn't initializing that first jump to #!dashboard, since you would need to init the Router controller before the call to `ready`.

Better to remove the first call to `ready` and take out the argument from the second. I have a demo of this at http://jsfiddle.net/air_hadoken/5maLu/1/ -- click Run and you will see evidence of each route listener in your controller firing.

Comment: thanks it worked. Now what I did was to download the latest version from their website and it still didnt worked, I download the one in your fiddle and it worked!. Thanks a lot, I needed to upgrade since the two way binding is a feature I must use now :D.